# How to lock screen rotation to current status

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I'm trying to lock the screen orientation to the position that was when the app was called, in order not to crash when the screen is rotated (yes, I've used

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

and it works fine on low Android versions, but it seems that for the higher ones it should be

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

and the screenSize parameter is not supported by the lower android versions).

So, I've tried this solution (1):

> setRequestedOrientation (
>   getResources().getConfiguration().orientation );

and this other one (2):

> setRequestedOrientation ( getScreenOrientation() );

where,

```
public int getScreenOrientation()
{
    Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;

        if(getOrient.getWidth() < getOrient.getHeight()){
            orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }else { 
             orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        }

    return orientation;
}
```

and, in both cases (1 and 2), the result is: 
When I launch the app in portrait orientation, it works fine. The screen orientation is locked to portrait mode.
But, when I do it in landscape orientation, it keeps changing the orientation.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just fix the source of your crash?

Comment: Exactly as CommonsWare said, what you should is not "lock" the orientation to avoid a crash in the first place (correctly save and restore state).

Comment: I absolutely second the point CommonsWare and Charlie COllins made.

Comment: You are right, that's what I should do. But, as you've noticed, I'm not an expert in Android, and I don't have any device with android 4.0 or higher to check it (I only know that it crashes when rotating it because a friend told me so) so I really don't know why it crashes on that higher versions. So I thought of this way around (anyway, it isn't awful, is it?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your orientation configuration is that, even if the device is in landscape orientation when the app is launched, the app will still be created in portrait mode, then switch to landscape if needed. Generally, unless it's a game, you shouldn't really force the orientation. You should fix the app so that it doesn't crash on orientation change.

Comment: Really, the app si so simple (it's only a main activity with two checkbox and one button from which it calls another activity made with phonegap) that I cannot imagine other way to fix it that the previous one. The main problem has more to do with the Android version than with the app.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you make a constant that is `Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` and just compare that with `getOrient` while using method 2. Then if they are equal set it to portrait, else set it to landscape.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work. The result is the same: Ok (locked) when in portrait position, not ok (not locked) in landscape. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user1728676 No problem. You really should try to fix the issue that is causing the crash as others have said. Also, I didn't know this but what jonbonazza said would cause my answer to not work anyway and that fact that it didn't work must mean that what he said is what happens and now we both know.